# How can I print different descriptions based on what the user selects from my list?

Tags: python

When a user selects from below list, I would like a different description to print with whatever foods is selected. I have tried using elif to separate the selections but instead when program is run, both inputs are printing.

```
foods = ['chocolate','yogurt', 'pineapple']

print(foods)

print(input('Select a food: '))

if 'chocolate' in foods:
  print('dark and bitter ')

if 'yogurt' in foods:
  print('creamy and smooth')
```

Comment: You don't use, or even assign, the user's input.

Comment: 'chocolate' is in 'foods'.  'yogurt' is in 'foods'.  You ask the program to print the food if they are in the list and that's what it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input()` [returns the line that was entered by the user](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#input). For example, the statement `selection = input('Select a food: ')` will assign the answer to the variable called `selection`.

The value of that variable can then be checked to determine which choice the user made.

```py
foods = ['chocolate','yogurt', 'pineapple']

print(foods)

selection = input('Select a food: ')

if selection == 'chocolate':
  print('dark and bitter')

elif selection == 'yogurt':
  print('creamy and smooth')
```